# Call function on pageload when ng-checked = true in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am building checkboxes dynamically using Angular. I set the ng-checked value based on a number of conditions.

The checkbox is appropriately checked on pageload. I need to call the makeAddressDefault() function (currently used in ng-click) on page load when ng-checked = true.

```
 <input type="checkbox" 
     id="defaultAddress{{$id}}" 
     ng-model="addressChecked" 
     name="defaultAddress" 
     ng-click="makeAddressDefault(add, $event)" 
     ng-checked="addresses.length === 1 || add.IsDefault() || isSelected(add.id)">
 <label ng-init="isAddressDefault(addresses, add)" for="defaultAddress{{$id}}">
     {{add.FirstName}} {{add.LastName}}<br />
     {{add.Address1}}<br />
     {{add.City}}, {{add.State}} {{add.ZIP}}
 </label>
```

What is the best way to handle this? Thanks!

Comment: Why not check the condition in your controller?

Comment: @Aer0 How so? I tried calling my function on ng-change, but ng-change isn't called on page load when the initial check of the checkbox happens.

Comment: Maybe that's not the best solution so far, but you could simply pass your `ng-checked` condition into an if condition in your controller. Just check wheter it's true or not and call your desired function. This for sure would require all variables to be accessible in your controller on load.

Comment: I don't think that would work since I'm looping through data, it's not the same every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller why don't you do something like

```
$scope.init = function(){
  angular.forEach(addresses, function(add){
    if(addresses.length === 1 || add.IsDefault() || isSelected(add.id)){
        makeAddressDefault(add)
    }
  })
}

$scope.init()
```

It will automatically call your init function once the controller has been initialized.

Comment: How would I know when the checkbox has been checked?

Comment: You could do similar logic for how your checking the 'checkedness' lol of the address in your html. See my revision

Comment: Interesting, I like it. I'll try it out. Thanks!